# Why won't my "hello world" program run?

Tags: java

When I'm compiling this code it gives me an error, what have I done wrong?

```
public class HelloPrinter
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       // Display a greeting in the console window

       System.out.println("Hello World");
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the compiler error message?

Comment: The code looks fine at first glimpse. Is it located in a file called `HelloPrinter.java`?

Comment: Downvoters: This is a perfectly legitimate, if really beginner question. We were all new at this once, give the poor dude a chance.

Comment: @Tenner OP may have also named a class `String` or have other code piece that's not posted here that gives problems.

Comment: @Tenner voters have been touched by that! :)

Comment: @Tenner from your second comment, yes, everybody was there some day. Apart from that, IMO posting a question that **shows no problem at all** is not a good question here.

Comment: @Adriano: Hooray! By the end of the day this question's going to be at zero (+152/-152).

Comment: @Tenner I didn't downvote, but it's still a poor question. Even a beginner can give more than a block of code and a "It doesn't work".

Comment: I agree. "an error" is not the most specific error description I've heard so far ;)

Comment: @user2964689 if you're a beginner here don't forget to accept the answer (if any) that helped you to solve your problem (for all your questions). That said, as you can imagine, people need more information to know what's going on (starting from complete error message).

Comment: @Adriano from the question current content, I really doubt there could be a good answer (at least that some OP's companion logs into SO and post the answer about the exact problem not posted in the question).

Comment: All: not disagreeing that the question isn't great. But the correct response (IMO) is @LuiggiMendoza's: "Tell us what exactly the error is." Five downvotes and question closure within two minutes doesn't help the OP's cause, nor turn him/her on to this site or programming in general. Now, hopefully s/he shows up again and tells us what the exact error message is...

Comment: @Tenner OP may be beginner in Java but not to the site (just look to OP's history), so he/she should already understand how the site works. Aso, if you were right, OP would have already replied and edited the question...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I agree but I miss time when there was an "acceptance score" so sometimes I like to remind it to new people...

Answer (score 1):

Everithing is OK with your code. Above code should be located in `HelloPrinter.java` file.

To compile this code you should run the following command:

```
javac HelloPrinter.java
```

To execute compiled code you should run this:

```
java HelloPrinter
```